# Skeleton Cocoapod Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I would like to develop a swift cocoa pod, however I'm having trouble figuring out out how to get started.

Cocoapods pre-release now has support for [swift](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/) however they do not currently have directions explaining how to create a new swift project pod.

The current guide on creating a pod is [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html) but its obj-c focused.

I posted a question to the repo and they said they do not currently have any example projects so I figured I'd turn to the community.

Thanks

Comment: One example here: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide now appears to be up to date.
[Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html)

The trick is to create a swift framework (swift must be used in a framework cocoa pod).

Follow the pod init guide and set the path to your classes as required (.swift instead of .h|.m